# SQL запрос UPDATE с группировкой

Tags: mysql, update

Есть таблица, в которой дублируются REF_DOC_ID.

```
REF_DOC_ID ARTICLE_ID Amount
1            1         10 
2            1         10
2            2         10 
3            2         10
```

Надо ее обновить к виду

```
REF_DOC_ID ARTICLE_ID Amount
 1            1         10 
 2            2         20
 3            2         10
```

То есть нужна группировка по REF_DOC и суммирование по Amount. 
Article_ID в любой сгруппированной строке должен быть 2. 
Помогите, пожалуйста, составить UPDATE. Пробовала много вариантов, не удается. Вот один из них

```
UPDATE `Test100` t1, (SELECT `REF_DOC_ID`, MIN(`ARTICLE_ID`) as 
`Min`, SUM(`Amount`) as `Sum` FROM `Test100` GROUP BY `REF_DOC_ID`) 
as `t2` CASE WHEN `t1`.`REF_DOC_ID` IN (SELECT REF_DOC_ID FROM 
(SELECT REF_DOC_ID, COUNT(*) as `num` FROM Test100 GROUP BY 
REF_DOC_ID) z WHERE `num`= 2) THEN DELETE FROM t1 
WHERE t1.`REF_DOC_ID`= z.`REF_DOC_ID` AND z.`num` = 2 
AND t1.`ARTICLE_ID`= t2.`MIN` END

SET t1.`REF_DOC_ID` = t2.`REF_DOC_ID`, t1.`ARTICLE_ID`=t2.`MAX`, 
t1.`Amount` = t2.`SUM`
```

Answer (score 2):

Для решения озвученной задачи UPDATE неприменим. Причина - кроме **обновления** части записей, требуется **удаление** остальных записей. Потому решение должно состоять минимум из 2 запросов.

Но самое простое (имхо) решение состоит из 3 запросов:

```
CREATE /* TEMPORARY */ TABLE temp (ref_doc_id INT
                                 , article_id INT
                                 , amount INT)
SELECT ref_doc_id
     , CASE COUNT(article_id) WHEN 1 THEN MAX(article_id) ELSE 2 END
     , SUM(amount)
FROM Test100
GROUP BY ref_doc_id;

TRUNCATE Test100;

INSERT INTO Test100 (ref_doc_id, article_id, amount)
SELECT ref_doc_id, article_id, amount
FROM temp;
```

Comment: Спасибо вам! А не могли бы вы подсказать, как реализовать через 2 запроса? Именно ст помощью update, без использования insert.

Comment: *как реализовать через 2 запроса? Именно с помощью update, без использования insert.* У Вас отсутствует поле, которое может являться идентификатором записи (хотя бы в группе), т.е. возможны две записи, являющиеся полными дубликатами. В этих условиях потребуется дополнительный нумерующий запрос, т.е. минимальное количество запросов станет равным опять-таки трём. Возможен вариант, когда всё-таки задача в этих условиях решается в 2 запроса, но изменится структура таблицы (да и не на каждой версии сработает) - добавится уникальный индекс по ref_doc_id, что вряд ли корректно.